# compare dates in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

For example I have in table row `finish` with values:

```
20-JAN-06;
21-SEP-06;
12-FEB-10;
15-MAR-09;
03-JUL-09;
23-JAN-09;
```

How can I compare them against `sysdate`? I know that this code is not correct:

```
Select name from project where finish <= sysdate ;
```

Comment: Why isn't that correct? Looks OK to me - depends on what you want it to do though I guess. Or is finish a varchar, in which case you should first format it to be a date.

Comment: finish is a date/timestamp column right? If not use the TO_DATE function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the ANSI standard `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`?

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE Finish <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef9cd/4)

Answer (score 1):

Something like that try cos I don't have oracle to test it

```
SELECT EMP_NAME, EMPNO
FROM EMP
WHERE TRUNC(START_DATE)  = TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

or

```
SELECT emp_name, empno
FROM emp
WHERE start_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) 
    and start_date  < TRUNC(SYSDATE)+1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select name 
from project 
where to_date(finish, 'DD-MON-YY') <= trunc(sysdate)
```